# Designing a bode diagram circuit

Tags: circuit-design, impedance-matching, low-pass, bode-plot

I have realized some low pass filters with a nominal cut off frequency around 10kHz, which I will use in combination with other filters to eliminate noise on DC and quasi-DC signals (around 30Hz).
I am now at the point where I need to test these filters and to be honest I never understood very well how the impedance matching works. I am using the internal oscillator of a lock in amplifier (up to 102kHz) as input signal, which has a 50ohm output impedance, and I am measuring amplitude and phase of the output signal using the signal channel of the same lock in, which has a 10MOhm termination. Will this affect the measured cut off frequency of the filters? Do I need to put a 50ohm feedthru after the load I’m measuring?

Edit: the schematics of the filter is the following

[image]

Comment: It depends on the filter design . It can be made for any impedance source and load. But not all are the same. Define specs or acceptance criteria with your question. And show simulation results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this low frequency range, it is not usual to work with the 50 Ohm system. This is rather used in the RF range, in which you want to achieve maximum power transfer. So you have both 50 Ohm output resistors and 50 Ohm input resistors (the actual value of the resistors can be different if they are all the same, e.g. in the 75 Ohm system).

In your comparatively low frequency range (extended audio range), however, one works with voltage matching. This means that you have relatively low output impedances and high impedance inputs.

So as long as your filter has a relatively high input resistance, e.g. in the kOhm range, the voltage drop across the 50 Ohm output resistance of the generator can be neglected. In addition, If your filter has a relatively low output impedance, you can connect it to the 10 MOhm input of your signal analyzer.

But note: This is how you would usually characterize a filter in this frequency range. However, if your filter contains e.g. a power opamp stage for driving low-impedance loads, you have to change your setup.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think my filters has a high input resistance (I've added the schematics to the question), but they do have a relatively low output impedance. However, when I test my filters, I observe a fairly good agreement with simulations, in particular at low frequencies, the ratio between the input signal and the output signal is one.